# What is the best way to represent editable options that change the viewport?

Tags: usability, gui-design, design, best-practice, dashboard

I am trying to figure out how what the best approach UI/UX wise is for the behavior I desire. I have a dashboard with a sidebar on the left, and all of the behavior I am describing happens on one page, so the sidebar is essentially static for my problem.

I've made a *very* rough draft of what the app will look like, essentially the dashboard will have a way to move between different galleries. The currently selected gallery is represented by the grid at the bottom with the big "+". The way to move between views will be in the area represented by "???". Behavior-wise, what I want is very similar to tabs in that I would like the user to be able to select an option and the option that is selected will change the gallery that is being displayed. However, I would like the various options to be editable in that I would like them to be able to be renamed and deleted, with potential support for reordering.

What would be the best approach for this?

[image]

Comment: You want the "tabs" to be editable?

Comment: If you want the options to be dynamic then do that. The style you choose to represent that (tabs, buttons, text links) is really up to you (the designer) to decide.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that selecting galleries is much more likely to be the main use case. And editing the selector is just a secondary use case.

Therefore it is crucial not to compromise the main use case in order to provide a secondary functionality.

Therefor I would suggest to have an edit mode. In edit mode the reanamig an reordering (by drag drop) would be the main case. This way you even have the opportunity to provide more space since the gallery area below is not of interest while reorganising the selector.